# How to update all records in collection except some specified fields

Tags: mongodb

There are many records with id in my collection. How can I update all records in collection except some specified fields, in this case id: 76956fbb42ef and eacae2244821.
Something like..

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').update(except {"id":"76956fbb42ef"} and{"id":"eacae2244821"}, {$set: {"startDate": "2022-09-22"}}, {multi:true})
```

This is a command I used to update for these two records, but there're many records, I can't do it one by one, how can I do this?

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').update({$or:[{"id":"76956fbb42ef"}, {"id":"eacae2244821"}]}, {$set: {"startDate": "2022-03-22"}}, {multi:true})
```

Comment: How about the `$nin` query operator?

Comment: I guess you are looking for `{_id: {$nin: ["76956fbb42ef", "eacae2244821"]}}`

Comment: $nin works good, thank you all!